# rails vanity routing and url shortener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-shortener, vanity

I am using vanity gem for email ab testing

in order to track clicks, I use vanity tutorial :

```
<%= link_to "see my page HERE", vanity_track_url_for(Vanity.context.vanity_identity, :metric, :controller => "controller" :action => "method", host => "myhost.com") %>
```

but I also use an url shortener to provides me perishable links (expires_at)

my rails routes contains :

```
  get '/s/:id' => "shortened_urls#show"
```

I add into it :

```
  resources :shortened_urls
```

so the vanity url_for is working when I use :

```
<%= link_to "see my page HERE too", vanity_track_url_for(Vanity.context.vanity_identity, :metric, :controller => "shortened_urls", :action => "show", :host => "myhost.com", :id => @short.unique_key) %>
```

but the url looks like **myhost.com/shortened_urls/aX5DtE5z69A**
and I want to have **myhost.com/s/aX5DtE5z69A**

I know how to do it with url rewriting in apach host :

```
    RewriteRule ^/shortened_urls/(.*)$ /s/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

but I would like to know if there is a shortcut in rails to do it :)

Comment: I just test the rewrite rule, it works like a charm :p

Comment: Note: Given how Ruby 1.9 has been around for ages now, the `controller: '...', action: '...', ...` style hash declarations are a lot shorter, more concise, and mirror what's done in other languages like JavaScript. The "hash rocket" from Ruby 1.8 `=>` is only necessary in cases where they key isn't a Symbol.